# Directive runs for every instance of bound components?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a directive that is used by multiple instances of the same component (eg,: input fields on a form).
But If I use one instance the directive functionality is triggered for every instance present in the current parent component.

How can you make sure that your directive is only works for the needed instance?

IF this is some bug/logic error on my side how can I get rid of it?

Exceptions is an object of arrays containing attributes to skip over,if they exists on target it's skipped otherwise emit the autosave event.

@Edit:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[InlineAutosave]'
})
export class AutosaveDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {

  readonly inlineDefaultExceptions: AutoSaveExceptions = {
    roles: [],
    classes: ['c-inline-editor',
      'form-control custom-inline-editor ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid',
      'form-control custom-inline-editor ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched',
      'editable-empty c-inline-editor',
      'form-control w-100 mb-2 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid',
      'form-control w-100 mb-2 ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched'],
    ids: ['inline-editor-save', 'inline-editor-cancel', 'pencilIcon']
  };

  private exceptionAttributes: AutoSaveExceptions;
  clicks$ = new Subject<HTMLElement>();
  changes$ = new BehaviorSubject<AutoSaveExceptions>(this.inlineDefaultExceptions);
  changeSub$: Subscription;
  clickSub$: Subscription;



  @Input() exceptions: AutoSaveExceptions;
  @Output() autosave = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.exceptionAttributes = this.inlineDefaultExceptions;
    this.changeSub$ = this.changes$.subscribe(exceptionObj => this.exceptionAttributes = exceptionObj);
    this.clickSub$ = this.clicks$.subscribe(target => this.handleClicks(target));
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes && changes['exceptions'] && changes['exceptions'].firstChange === true) {
      this.changes$.next(changes['exceptions'].currentValue);
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.changeSub$.unsubscribe();
    this.clickSub$.unsubscribe();
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(target: HTMLElement) {
    this.clicks$.next(target);
  }

  private handleClicks(target: HTMLElement) {
    if (target.hasAttribute('id')) {
      if (target.attributes.getNamedItem('id').value !== undefined) {
        const targetId = target.attributes.getNamedItem('id').value;
        if (this.exceptionAttributes.ids.indexOf(targetId) < 0) {
          console.log('autosave ID');
          this.autosave.emit();
        }
      }
    } else if (target.hasAttribute('class')) {
      if (target.attributes.getNamedItem('class').value !== undefined) {
        const targetClass = target.attributes.getNamedItem('class').value;
        if (this.exceptionAttributes.classes.indexOf(targetClass) < 0) {
          console.log('autosave CLASS');
          this.autosave.emit();
        }
      }
    } else if (target.hasAttribute('role')) {
      if (target.attributes.getNamedItem('role').value !== undefined) {
        const targetRole = target.attributes.getNamedItem('role').value;
        if (this.exceptionAttributes.roles.indexOf(targetRole) < 0) {
          console.log('autosave ROLE');
          this.autosave.emit();
        }
      }
    } else if (target === this.elementRef.nativeElement) {
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: My best guess is, the directive is modifying some object that it got by reference, and the reference is shared across all children... But without any code to look at, it's only a wild guess.

Comment: It's hard to provide some code since i want to modify some inline-editor behavior (add autosave when condition happens) but that inline-editor is copied from other source by other ppl. But the directive only emits a void event when a condition happens. So it has nothing to do with the editor's value.

Comment: you could try to at least provide the directive